# How to use environment variables to put them in AWS SAM template

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-cognito, aws-sam

I have a AWS SAM template that has lines like this

```
Parameters:
    GoogleClientId:
        Description: 'Required. The Google client id'
        Type: 'String'
        NoEcho: true

    GoogleClientSecret:
        Description: 'Required. The Google client password'
        Type: 'String'
        NoEcho: true

Resources:
...
  GoogleProvider:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolIdentityProvider
    Properties:
      AttributeMapping: {
        "name": "name",
        "family_name": "family_name",
        "email": "email",
        "username": "sub",
      }
      ProviderDetails: {
         "client_id" : !Ref GoogleClientId,
         "client_secret": !Ref GoogleClientSecret,
         "authorize_scopes": "openid profile email",
      }
      ProviderName: Google
      ProviderType: Google
      UserPoolId: !Ref ScreenshotUserPool
...
```

I don’t want to keep the Google secret in the clear, I have it in the .env file.

I found an option with parameters, but I don’t want to re-enter the parameters with each deployment, is there a way to automatically pull the variable from the environment?
thanks to all

Comment: Use Secrets Manager to store the value and then use dynamic references in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your current deployment process.

For local development using the `.env` environment is your best bet though.

For deployments you can use AWS Secrets Manager to retrieve the sensitive information (specifically using [get-secret-value](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/get-secret-value.html)) and pass it in using the `parameter-overrides` flag with `sam deploy`.

You can wrap this up in a bash script and have that be executed when you're ready for a deployment, the below is just an example pseudocode.

```
# deploy.sh file

# retrieve secret from AWS Secrets Manager
# you can use jq to extract specifics if you're storing a JSON
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id MyGoogleClientSecret --output text)

# build
sam build

# deploy
sam deploy \
--stack-name {STACK_NAME} \
--parameter-overrides GoogleClientSecret=$GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET \
--no-confirm-changeset
```

Note `--no-confirm-changeset` will result in a deployment without the prompt to confirm, *use cautious*.